# When hiding the tool bar hide it 100%

Tags: windows-7, desktop, toolbar

I am using windows 7. I have set the toolbar to auto-hide. for some reason I can still see the 1 row of pixel form the toolbar even when it is hidden. Any way to make that row invisible?

[image]

Comment: @JasonC with this tool if I hide the bar completely I can no longer mouse down to open it. I still want to mouse down to bring it up.

Comment: there are other tools listed there that do that, did you try them? There's also that one guys shybar tool, which had a broken link but I posted an updated link in the comments just now. Haven't tried it. I mean, there's no way to do it natively unfortunately, no registry tweaks or anything like that, so you'll have to hunt around for a tool to do it. Also check google for "windows 7 hide taskbar completely" - those results looked promising... Sorry cant link easily from iPad.